# Swift Design Choice - Protocol or Class? (mimicking Java's Abstract Class)

Tags: swift, design-patterns, swift-protocols

I'm making Tetris. What is the best solution for shared code amongst the pieces? A class, protocol, or something else?

Tetrimino template capabilities:

```
func moveDown()
func rotateRight() // based on data table
func rotateLeft()  // based on data table
```

Each type of piece can rotate and move, but the way it rotates is determined by unique data tables. The data tables are the same between all instances of that piece (e.g. all long pieces rotate in the same way), and there is mainly shared functionality upon initialization.

It would make sense to use a protocol with a static variable for the data tables, and a default constructor that is run by conforming classes before running their unique code.

However, with a protocol, the static variables cannot be overridden, nor can a base initializer be provided that conforming classes can add onto. But if I use a class to get around these problems, then Tetrimino instances can be made, when it should just be a template.

What's the best design pattern for this?

Answer (score 1):

Using a protocol with default implementations as your abstraction layer can work for your requirements.

You can declare the `dataTable` as a static requirement and then from conforming classes, you can make the variable a `class` variable in case it's computed and you want it to be overridable from subclasses or if it's a stored property, then subclasses can change its value even when it's `static` (stored properties need to be `static` anyways).

As for sharing common initialisation code, you can add a `static` function with a default implementation to your protocol, then call that static function from the init of conforming types.

```
protocol TetrisPiece {
  static var dataTable: [String] { get }
  /// Method to be run when creating a new piece
  static func setup()
}

extension TetrisPiece {
  static func setup() {
    print("Doing common stuff")
  }
}

class SquarePiece: TetrisPiece {
  static var dataTable: [String] = []

  init() {
    Self.setup()
    // Do the custom init here
  }
}
```

Comment: What if `extension TetrisPiece` also has `func rotateRight()` that accesses the `static var dataTable`? If I create a new `SquarePiece` instance and run `squarePiece.rotateRight()`, does it access the static dataTable from `SquarePiece` or from `TetrisPiece`?

Comment: @NathanShie the protocol doesn't have a default value for the static property, only conforming types do, so the value will be taken from the concrete conforming type

Comment: Oh right, I forgot. Thank you for the help!

Comment: wait there is an error: `Static member 'dataTable' cannot be used on instance of type 'Self'` when trying to access dataTable from the TetrisPiece extension

Comment: @NathanShie from instance methods, you need to access static properties using `Self` or the type name, so do `Self.dataTable`